# How do I redirect routes in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am working in rails. I created an xml file, uploaded, and when i access it using this URL it's working:

```
http:://localhost:3000/abc.xml
```

But I want to redirect the request to another URL:

```
http:://localhost:3000/xyz
```

I this code in my routes file, but it is not working.

```
get '/abc.xml', to: redirect('/xyz')

Rails -v 
3.2.1
```

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Rails 3

```
match "/abc.xml" => redirect("/xyz")
```

Rails 4

```
get '/abc', to: redirect('/xyz')
```